# Behaviour behind python's intersection update for sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary that maps values to sets.
I want to create a variable from one of my dictionary values and perform set intersections with some of the other values in the dictionary.

When I call the set intersection update on this new variable, my original dictionary is changed, any ideas why?

It almost seems like firstElem points to the dictionary, rather than being a new variable itself.

```
exampleDictionary = {'first':{'a','b','c','d'},'second':{'c','d'}}

firstElem = exampleDictionary['first']
firstElem.intersection_update(exampleDictionary['second'])

print(firstElem)
# {'c', 'd'}

print(exampleDictionary)
# {'first': {'c', 'd'}, 'second': {'c', 'd'}}
```

Thank you

Comment: You're exactly right - `firstElem` is indeed a reference to the same object as the reference held by the dictionary.

Comment: How can I save the value at a key to a new variable without mutating the original dictionary? Using the access [] notation and the .get() method both refer to the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right - `firstElem` is indeed a reference to the same object as the reference held by the dictionary.

If you don't want this to happen, you could just use the `intersection()` method, which returns a new set, as opposed to `intersection_update()` which updates in place.

```py
>>> exampleDictionary = {'first':{'a','b','c','d'},'second':{'c','d'}}
>>> firstElem = exampleDictionary['first'].intersection(exampleDictionary['second'])
>>> print(exampleDictionary)
{'first': {'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'}, 'second': {'c', 'd'}}
>>> print(firstElem)
{'c', 'd'}
```